# ASIHTTPRequest appendPostData not working

Tags: iphone, post, asihttprequest

I want to send String Data to a php server using the ASIHTTPRequest appendPostData method but its not working.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request appendPostData:[@"123456" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

I tried some modifications on the request itself like:

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request buildPostBody];
```

but also this does not work.

When i use the

```
[request addPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"names"];
```

syntax it does work.

Anybody has an idea whats wrong here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use this:

```
- (void)performPostRequestWithString:(NSString *)string stringDictionary:(NSDictionary *)stringDictionary dataDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary delegate:(id)requestDelegate requestSelector:(SEL)requestSelector errorSelector:(SEL)errorSelector {

    //localCopy = self;

    self.delegate = requestDelegate;
    self.callback = requestSelector;
    self.errorCallback = errorSelector;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

    postRequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [postRequest setDelegate:self];
    [postRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    if (stringDictionary)
        for (NSString *key in [stringDictionary allKeys])
            [postRequest setPostValue:[stringDictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];

    if (dataDictionary)
        for (NSString *key in [dataDictionary allKeys])
            [postRequest setData:[dataDictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];

    //NSLog(@"request url = %@", [postRequest.url absoluteString]);
    [postRequest startAsynchronous];
}
```

Parameters:

- `(NSString *)string` - url string, where to post your request;
- `(NSDictionary *)stringDictionary` - dictionary, which contains all the text information (such as name, id etc.);
- `(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary` - dictionary, which contains all data information (such as photos, files, etc.);
- `(id)requestDelegate` - delegate to perform selectors below;
- `(SEL)requestSelector` - selector, which will be executed while successfully request;
- `(SEL)errorSelector` - selector, which will be executed, while error occurred.

P.S. Selectors will be used in the `ASIHTTPRequest Delegate` implementation